# Change freemarker Single Select macro by jquery

Tags: freemarker, spring-form

I am using `<@spring.formSingleSelect "PersonalInfoBean.district" distMap! ""/>` **freemarker macro** to display a select option in `ftl` page. where `distMap` is a `HashMap<String, String>`contains the districts as `key(distId)`, `value(distName)`. And its work fine.

Now I want to change the options/distMap dynamically(from another select onchange) using javascript like ajax and fetching data from server-side. I am using SpringMVC. I am able to fetch `String` or `json` data from server by ajax call. But can't replace that `distMap`/`options`.

Comment: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - Freemarker on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript (i.e. AJAX) in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. Your `distMap`, `options` etc. simply do not exist anymore in the browser, only the generated HTML code.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek But this macro `<@spring.formSingleSelect "PersonalInfoBean.district" distMap! "style='--'"/>` gives me `<select name="district" id="district" style='--'></select>` tag with options in ftl page, therefore can't I remove/replace the options ?

Comment: You can manipulate the options of the select element (using Javascript), of course - just be aware you are manipulating the DOM objects in the browser, not the data model on the server.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Really I can't change even the DOM after render/load the HTML in the page.

Comment: Show your (Javascript) code.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Thank you very much to replay me a lot. Finally I detect the culprit. That was the `class='chosen-select'`. This `chosen-select` class let me not update the options. I used this class in `<select>` that's why i was in trouble. How can I resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem after a day. I used `chosen-select` in `<select class="chosen-select">` DOM.

I change the update script by....

```
$(target).empty().append(options).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

and it works.